# Fstab doesn't update permissions or ownership rules

Tags: mount, permissions, sudo, fstab, fat32

I mount a FAT32 filesystem (because it needs to be compatible with windows) that has an SVN repository on it. It is mounted with owners `root:plugdev` and permissions `rwxrwx---` . My user account is a member of `plugdev`, so I can edit my files fine.

However, when I try to commit to the SVN repository I get the following message:

```
Transmitting file data .svn: E000001: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E000001: Can't set permissions on '/media/data/SVN/Electronics/.svn/tmp/svn-dk1XN3': Operation not permitted
```

This is of course because my user isn't the owner of that file. I can commit with `sudo svn ci`. But I'm lazy, and typing `sudo`  starts to annoy me.

I've tried many changes to the `/etc/fstab` file looking all over the internet and have come up with this:

```
UUID=EA08-6773 /media/data vfat umask=007,gid=1000,uid=1000,dmask=0000,fmask=0000,utf8,allow_other,user 0 0
```

I am user `1000`. The line used to be:

```
UUID=EA08-6773 /media/data vfat defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0 0
```

So I changed the permissions mask for both files and directories, added `uid` and changed `gid`,  and added `allow_other` and `user`. This last change did make that I can now mount the volume without `sudo`, but for the rest **none of these changes have any effect.** The permissions are not updated, and the owner is still `root:plugdev`.

The permissions of the mountpoint `/media/data` are `rwxrwxr-x` for `camilstaps:root` (but when I mount this changes to `root:plugdev` automatically).

How can I let fstab mount this FAT32 volume with me as owner, so that I can change permissions?

---

#### Response to request in the comments

```
camilstaps@lenovo:~$ groups camilstaps
camilstaps : camilstaps adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev fuse lpadmin sambashare
```

``` grep ``whoami`` /etc/passwd ``` with single back-ticks returns:

```
camilstaps:x:1000:1000:Camil:/home/camilstaps:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Ownership and permissions of vfat / ntfs are set at the time of mounting as defaults and since Windows formats do not support ownership & permissions you cannot change them.

Comment: @oldfred can I change the defaults?

Comment: i am no expert on settings for Windows formats. I used user,auto,fmask=0113,dmask=0002 for my FAT32 partition, but have not used FAT32 since 2010 after I found it was truncating all my files over 4GB and had no journal. Use NTFS if you have larger files.

Comment: @oldfred unfortunately, that doesn't have any effect either. Thanks anyway! I used NTFS at first, but files that I added with ubuntu weren't visible in Windows, so I changed to FAT32. The large files are a minus point. Fortunately, I have a large ext4 filesystem for Ubuntu and NTFS for Windows. When I need to share large files between the two, I split them up.

Comment: Have a read at the link above. FAT32 plainly and sipmly *doesn't support permissions*.  **Permissions on FAT32 are only simulated**.

Comment: @Fabby thanks very much, that helps. If there were a way to mount the filesystem as myself though, that would be fine as well. Or a way to alter the simulation behaviour. Is there?

Comment: That is an entirely [new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask), but the short answer is: yes there is a way! :P  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby actually I intended to ask that as well (see the last line of my question) - could you perhaps write an answer for that, or point me to one? :)

Comment: I would need the output of `grep 'whoami' /etc/passwd` where the ' are actually ` and `groups` of the user that is running the `svn commit` command...

Comment: editing answer... (against my better judgement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The owner of the svn repository needs to be changed by:

   ```
   sudo chown --recursive camilstaps:plugdev /Path/To/Dir/*
   ```
2. The FAT partition needs to be mounted using:

   ```
   UUID=EA08-6773 /media/data vfat gid=1000,uid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137,nosuid,nodev,users 0 2
   ```

Comment: test it first before you accept!  :P  ;-)